# Flutter Image.network loading builder not working for web

Tags: flutter, image, dart

In my `Web` project I am using `Image.network` so load images. That is working fine. But now I want to add a [`SkeletonAvatar`](https://pub.dev/packages/skeletons) as `loadingBuilder` but it is never displayed.

This is what I tried:

```
Image.network(
      imageUrl,
      loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
        if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
        return SkeletonAvatar(
          style: SkeletonAvatarStyle(
            height: height,
            width: width,
          ),
        );
      },
      errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
        return const Icon(Icons.error);
      },
      height: height,
      width: width,
      fit: boxFit,
    )
```

When printing the `loadingProgress` this is the output:

> null
>
> ImageChunkEvent#fe60b(cumulativeBytesLoaded: 770205, expectedTotalBytes: 770205)
>
> null

What am I missing here? You could add any Widget for `loadingBuilder`. Non is showing up.

Comment: Can you include more about `SkeletonAvatar`

Comment: Maybe it is just loaded too quickly? I mean a 750 Kbyte image can be loaded pretty quickly. Try some throttling in the browser (in Chrome, within dev tools, under Network, where you see `No throttling`, select `Slow 3G` for example.)

Comment: yap, it is fast, you can change the  image like `'https://picsum.photos/3350?image=9',`

Comment: @PeterKoltai I tried it. And it is not working correctly. It is showing *nothing* while loading and right before it is loaded the `loadingBuilder` is shown for a millisecond.

Comment: And if you try to use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image), with the `progressIndicatorBuilder`, is there any difference?

Comment: @PeterKoltai `CachedNetworkImage` is not available for web. I found another package, which does the job. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For now I couldn't make it work with `Image.network` but I found this package: [NetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/image_network).

And with its `onLoading`, I get the desired result.

**EDIT**

This is also not working perfectly. Since it is always reloading the images. At least `Image.network` does some sort of `caching`. Both options are not ideal.